# Spring Rest RequestMethod.GET returns 400 Bad Request for @RequestParam required=true when missing

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring and Rest Endpoints.

I have a controller,  which accepts `@RequestParam` and returns a `JSON Response`.

By default the `@RequestParam required = "true"`, which is how  I need it.

I am using Spring 3.1.3

This is my Get Method in the controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/path")
public class MyController{
        @RequestMapping(value = "/search/again.do", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {
        "application/json"
    })
    public ResponseEntity<?> find(@RequestParam(value = "test", required = true) final String test) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Success ", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

When I send a get with the request param it hits the endpoint , which is how I expect.

Example : path/search/again.do?test=yes

Everything is perfect.

**This is where I am having issue:**

When I send a Get with that value missing:

Example: path/search/again.do

I get a 400 Bad Request. May be this is correct.

But what I want to achieve is. When the required value is missing in the GET request.

I can send a JSON response as that `@RequestParam` Value **test** is missing.

Can anybody guide me how to achieve this.

I am not sure what I am missing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look closely at your code, you'll see that the answer is staring right at you.  Just change `required` to `false` and you should be good to go.  When the user doesn't provide a value for GET parameter `test`, then you can return a special message.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/path")
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search/again.do", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {
    "application/json"
    })
    public ResponseEntity<?> find(@RequestParam(value = "test", required = false) final String test) {
        if (test == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("test parameter is missing", HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        else {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("Success ", HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I know I can change that required = false and everything works how I want it to. But I want the required = true CONDITION to be there and when anyone using the endpoint doesn't send that value, some how validate that request by sending a response that he forgot to send the test value. I don't want to keep it false. Isn't this possible?

Comment: What is the problem with setting `required = false`?  The framework was designed to throw an Exception if the parameter be missing.  If you don't want that behavior, then set `required = false` and implement your own logic to handle it.

Comment: I just feel that when I make the value required=false. I give a person to enter the endpoint. I am aware that I can use javax validations and add some @Valid and handle it by giving a error message but I don't know if I can do it on RequestParams.

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1: You can use custom @ExceptionHandler in your controller, e.g

```
@ExceptionHandler(MissingServletRequestParameterException.class)
public ResponseEntity<?> paramterValidationHandler(HttpServletResquest request){
 //validate the request here and return an ResponseEntity Object
}
```

Solution 2: Would be custom spring ErrorController which I never have tried myself but it possible to override it.

Solution 3:  You can write an ControllerAdvice for a global controller exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you set the parameter test is required. U just can't send the request without that param. Try to change the param required= false and handle the missing param in the method. You can us something like`if(test==null) throw new Exception("Param test missing")`

Comment: thanks for the feedback , I am aware about that. I was wondering that isn't there a  way to Validate a request and send error message back. By keeping that value as required= true.

By making it false and handling that in the method is not making sense to me? May be this won't  be possible but I see many people asking about the same thing.

Comment: Are you trying to handle this in global. Then try to search spring doc for exception handling. But as I see it. The solution with handling the missing parameter in method is good practice.

Comment: I think he either needs `required = false` or he needs to override the default behavior of the framework.  The easy choice is clear.

Comment: @all appreciate all the feedback. I was wondering if this is possible but seems like something like this is not implemented yet.  There is a improvement filled in Spring Jira to have this feature using javax validation. Which can help me in future  here is the link : https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6380